# Dumb Question: How do I make AVPlayer look like everyone else's?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

### My Current Setup (Subject to Change)

I have a simple iOS app right now that plays an M3U8 using AVPlayer. In order to place custom UI elements on top of the player (text alerts, mostly) I jimmy-rigged what is probably a **terrible** architecture, and I'm open to the idea of scrapping the whole thing and starting over.

- First I created a new UIView which I called "MyPlayer". This UIView has a XIB file with nothing in it
- Next I created a new NSObject (now UIView) which I called "PlayerDisplay". This class also has a XIB file associated with it, which contains an ImageView and a Label
- In `MyPlayer.m`'s init method, I instantiate a `PlayerDisplay` using an `initWithMyPlayer` method
- In `PlayerDisplay.m`'s initWithMyPlayer method, I created an `AVPlayerViewController` instance
- I called `[myPlayer addSubview:controller.view]` and `controller.view.frame = myPlayer.bounds` to get the player to display within my view
- I called `[[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] loadNibNamed:@"PlayerDisplay" owner:self options:nil]` to load the XIB with the ImageView and Label
- I called `[myPlayer addSubview:self.contentView]` and `self.contentView.frame = myPlayer.bounds` to get the player to display my ImageView and Label over top of the player

It felt hack-y at the time, and it feels hack-y now. But it allows me to insert a single `MyPlayer` view into an app and have it load all of my custom control and display logic. And it works (at least as far back as iOS 8, which is the oldest I've tested, and as far forward as iOS 12.4, which is the newest I've tested)

However I recently wanted to look into creating custom controls and looked to some industry leaders for inspiration (Netflix, YouTube, etc) - and I noticed that ***every other video player on the market looks the same***, but none of them look like mine.

### Netflix

[image: A sample of Netflix's iOS player]

### ESPN

[image: A sample of ESPN's iOS player]

### Hulu

[image: A sample of Hulu's iOS player]

### Amazon Prime

[image: A sample of Amazon Prime's iOS player]

### YouTube

[image: A sample of YouTube's iOS player]

### Twitch

[image]

Every one of these players has:

- White icons with transparent backgrounds placed directly on top of the video (no control bar background)
- A play/pause button in the dead center of the video
- Seek back/forward buttons on either side of the play button
- A seek bar at the bottom of the video
- A single icon in the top-left
- A horizontal list of icons in the top-right

Not only that, but Netflix and ESPN use the exact same <s>icon set</s> seek icons (although upon further inspection, the play buttons and cast buttons differ slightly)

<s>Similarly, Hulu and Amazon Prime use the exact same icon set</s> It was pointed out that Hulu and Amazon Prime differ sufficiently to be different icon sets. I still stand by Netflix and ESPN having identical seek buttons, though. I've rearranged the pictures to make this more obvious

It's too unbelievable to me that every single company disabled the default controls, built their own user interface from scratch, and they all ***just so happened*** to look identical. I feel like either AVPlayer has an option to enable this layout, Apple provides a framework for building UIs from icon sets which lays things out in this manner, or there may be a third-party library that is considered the "de facto" standard for video streaming, much like ExoPlayer is the leading name on Android

Compare and contrast all of the above players with ***my*** player, which is using Apple's default UI for an `AVPlayerViewController`:

[image: MyPlayer]

- The control bar has a background color and rounded corners
- The play button is within the control bar
- There are no seek forward / back buttons
- There's only a volume control in the top right instead of a list of icons

### How do I make my player look like theirs?

Is there just a flag in AVPlayer to say "use the other UI"? Is there a third-party library I should be using? What am I doing differently from all of the big names?

Note: I did discover [AVPlayerViewControlsStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avplayerviewcontrolsstyle), which I should theoretically be able to utilize with `avPlayerView.controlsStyle = ...`, however as you can tell from my setup above - I don't actually have an instance of `AVPlayerView`. Just my own custom view and the `AVPlayerViewController`. I tried typing `controller.view.controlsStyle` into Xcode to see if it would auto-complete, but it did not - making me think I don't have an `AVPlayerView` *at all*

Second Note: I also saw `AVPlayerLayer` when looking through the official Apple docs. What is that used for? Should I be utilizing it?

Comment: @RobNapier I believed they were the same because the seek-forward and seek-back icons looked basically identical as far as my eyes could discern. Even looking at the "1" in 10, they both have a single hook at the top of the one with no base at the bottom, and the hook is approximately 30 degrees below the horizontal and about 1/4th the height of the number. Both Netflix and ESPN have a circle starting at about 45 degrees above the horizontal and continuing counter-clockwise until they are above the "10", then have a double-arrowhead with sharp corners. You can't deny the similarity.

Comment: @RobNapier Looking more closely at Hulu and Amazon Prime, I can see the differences in those. Their 1's are slightly different and the arrow heads are slightly different. I just missed that at a glance. Netflix and ESPN, though -- those are identical. Also, whether or not the icon sets are the same is irrelevant to the general question. Is there some library or framework being used to create these common layouts?

Comment: No; the point of them images is that they all built these from scratch. They're similar because there are certain common themes that everyone copies, but they're all unique. ("Scratch" perhaps being excessive. You can build all these on top of AVPlayer just using custom controls. I don't know how each of these was built.)

Comment: Netflix and ESPN are also not close to identical. Look at the corners on the play triangle. (There are lots of other differences of course, but start there.) We may mean different things by "close." If you can look at it without a tool like xScope and see differences, IMO it's not close.

Comment: As I commented, and as I clarified in the question, I was looking at the SEEK buttons which, as far as I can tell, are identical. That said, it's STILL irrelevant to the question. I find it unbelievable that every single video app built a UI from scratch and they all **just happen** to look identical. It feels like there may be some framework, library, Cocoapod, or design standard they are all using. Even if they WERE all built from scratch, the question remains how I make my player look like that. How do I make custom elements for an AVPlayerViewController?

Comment: Do you mean the +10 and -10 buttons? They're not identical either; they have different fonts and different weights. I've built these UIs. They're custom. That's why they all look different (sometimes very different, sometimes slightly, but none of the ones you've shown here are identical). Generally you use custom overlays (see `contentOverlayView` and `customOverlayViewController`). They're mostly just buttons and custom artwork. They're all built from scratch, and they happen to often look very similar, but not identical.

Comment: Having worked at one of these streaming companies ... custom icons. One thing to also think about. Designs tend to converge on the latest trends. Which is why you see what looks like "identical" designs. For these types of companies, the overhead for doing custom icons and updating the code is trivial.